# Show Listview on googlemaps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

I'm trying to show list view on the bottom side of the google maps activity (only when the button is clicked), but it doesn't work, just showing app stop message. How can I show listview on google maps activity?

Here is my java and xml code

```
package com.example.dong_gyo.project;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapFind extends ActionBarActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    LocationManager lm;
    String locationProvider;
    Location location;
    Button mapListbut;
    ListView mapList;
    ArrayList list;
    ButtonListener listener;
    ArrayAdapter mapadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_find);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mapListbut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showMapList);

        mapadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        mapList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mapList);
        mapList.setAdapter(mapadapter);
        mapList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mapListbut.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
             // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

            lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationProvider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            final LatLng LOC = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOC, 16));

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap(LOC);
            }
        }   
    }


    private void setUpMap(LatLng LOC) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOC));
    }


    class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // 목록 토글 버튼 리스너
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()) { //
                case R.id.showMapList:
                    if (!mapList.isShown()) {
                        mapList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mapadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mapListbut.setSelected(true);
                    } else {
                        mapList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mapListbut.setSelected(false);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                startActivity(new Intent(SearchManager.INTENT_ACTION_GLOBAL_SEARCH));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showMapList"
        android:text = "목록보기"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mapList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#eeeeee"  >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat message..

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it said it gets a null pointer. Looking at your code, `location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);` makes `location` to be null. So, instead of the `getBestProvider`, try:

```
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
```

I tried it and the maps load.